# instapy: unable to determine correct filename for 64bit macos

Tags: python, instapy

I am trying to use instapy and it does not work for some reason. It gives me this message: unable to determine correct filename for 64bit macos
I tried to solve it with
'brew install geckodriver' as I saw suggested, but it did not work.

Please is there any chance you could help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.